# GNUPLOT: how to only print selected row?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I'm using GNUPLOT with a PC.  Is there a way to only plot some selected rows from a data file instead of every rows?
for example I have the following data file:

   **80000.00       1000.000       234.4000

   10000.00       2000.000       237.2000

   20000.00       3000.000       240.0000

   30000.00       4000.000       242.8000

   40000.00       5000.000       245.3000

   10000.00       1000.000       247.4000

   20000.00       2000.000       249.7000

   30000.00       3000.000       252.8000

   10000.00       1000.000       257.7000

   20000.00       2000.00        263.4000

   30000.00       3000.00        269.6000

   10000.00       1000.00        275.8000

   20000.00       2000.00        280.3000

   30000.00       3000.00        286.7000**    
What if I only want to plot all the second column with value "1000"?  Any tricks to do this?  Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30522520/2604213

Answer (score 0):

GNUPLOT has an "every" option which you need to use.

```
plot "data.txt" every ::10::100
```

will plot all data from line 10 to line 100. 
Leaving any of the two line nos. blank will result in GNUPLOT plotting from the first line / till the last line.

An alternative, time intensive method is to comment out the lines you don't want plotted. But the above method is of course much better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what I'm looking for is to only plot those record which the 2nd column value ="1000".  So basically I will only plot the 1st column as y-axis and the 3rd column as x-axis with 2nd col value is equal to 1000.  Any method to do this?  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using awk. It should work

```
plot "<awk '
```

followed by the usual commands