# gnuplot: Connect points even when missing/invalid are inbetween

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file with interleaving data rows from different devices.

Now, I'd like to plot data from one devices `with linepoints` and use this to filter only the device of interest:

```
plot 'datafile' using (<someCondition> ? $1 : 1/0):2
```

Now, gnuplot does not connect the points because there is always some invalid data inbetween.

**Is it possible to make gnuplot to connect my points?**

By the way: This is a Windows machine, so an external sed/awk/whatever command is no option.

Comment: Here is a solution which works certainly for gnuplot>=4.4.0 (March 2010) https://stackoverflow.com/a/54475591/7295599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since gnuplot version 5.0.6 you can use `set datafile missing NaN` to have invalid points treated as missing ones, and drawing `with lines` or `with linespoints` simply ignores those points and connects the others

```
$data <<EOD
12
27
0
23
42
EOD

set multiplot layout 1,2

set title '0.0 invalid'
plot $data using 0:($1 == 0.0 ? 1/0 : $1) with linespoints pt 7 notitle

set title '0.0 invalid but treated as missing'
set datafile missing NaN
replot
unset multiplot
```

Output with 5.0.6:

[image]