# The conditional plotting with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm new on gnuplot.

Can anyone help me plot with condition?

I know there is something like if statement, but I have no idea

how to deal with it and it looks like it's not appropriate to what I want to do.

I have a data set like this,

```
6  1   3   -9  
7  2   2   -9      
5  2   2   4   
4  3   5   5  
5  4   1   3  
3  4   1   -9
```

So I have 6 rows and 4 columns.

What I want to do is to plot a graph using ($1-$2):($3-$4),

but if an element in column 4 is -9, then the rows that have -9 won't be plotted.

Therefore, the graph will only show the data of row 3,4, and 5.

```
Plot 'text.txt' u ($1-$2):($3-$4)
```

How can I apply that concept on the above command?

Comment: Add this line: `set datafile missing '-9'`

Comment: plot 'text.txt' u ($1-$2):($4 != -9 ? $3-$4 : NaN)

Comment: Like user8153 said ^. The structure of a conditional in gnuplot is as follows : `<condition> ? <what to do if true> : <what to do if false>`. It's actually the same as in C++. In this specific example, when gnuplot encounters NaN (i.e. whenever the value in the fourth column is -9), it won't plot anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30522035/2604213

Comment: Thank you guys! That's what I was looking for!